# How do I return an instance of an object of the same type as the class passed in using Java 6?

Tags: java, generics

I want to return an instance of an object of same type of the Class object passed in. The type passed in can be ANYTHING. Is there a way to do this with Generics?

To clarify -- I don't want the caller of the method to not have to cast to the Class of the object they passed in

For example,

```
public Object<Class> getObject(Class class)
{
  // Construct an instance of an object of type Class

  return object;
}

// I want this:
MyClass myObj = getObject(MyClass.class);

// Not this (casting):
MyClass myObj = (MyClass)getObject(MyClass.class);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume you want to create a new instance of that class. This would not be possible using generics (you can't call `new T()`) and would also be quite limited using reflection.

The reflection approach could be:

```
//class is a reserved word, so use clazz
public <T> T getObject(Class<T> clazz) {
  try {
    return clazz.newInstance();
  }
  catch( /*a multitude of exceptions that can be thrown by clazz.newInstance()*/ ) {
    //handle exception
  }
}
```

Note that this only works if the class has a no-argument constructor.

However, the question would by why you need that instead of just calling 
`new WhatEverClassYouHave()`.

Comment: Interesting you should say a multitude of exceptions given what the actual implementation of `Class.newInstance` can throw.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Well, there are at least two exceptions but I didn't want to write those since that's not the point here. :) When dealing with reflection you often have many more, depending on what you do.

Comment: I'm not actually doing a "newInstance()". Had I been doing that, then I would not have needed to cast. The instance already exsits. The method is looking it up in a cache and returning it

Comment: @Thomas I think there might be more than two exception types, or you could look at it as fewer.

Comment: @BestPractices If you're just trying to cast the object, `Class.cast` is you accomplice. (Most uses of reflection merely reflect confusion.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline yes, as I said "at least two exceptions" and "often many more" :) - as useful as reflection can be, as hard it is to get right.

Comment: Just to be clearer, the best practice is _not_ to depend on the exact implementation of the input in your output.

Comment: @BestPractices - The cast shouldn't be necessary if you pass in a `Class<T>` instead of a `Class`.

Answer (score 5):

```
public <C> C getObject(Class<C> c) throws Exception 
{ 
    return c.newInstance(); 
}
```

Usage Example:

```
static <C> C getObject(Class<C> c) throws Exception { 
    return c.newInstance();
}

static class Testing {
    {System.out.println("Instantiated");}
    void identify(){ System.out.println("Invoked"); }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Testing t = getObject(Testing.class);
    t.identify();
}
```

Comment: Still, getObject does not add anything. You can simply use:  Testing t = Testing.class.newInstance(); and get rid of the getObject method

Comment: @Puce- Example added to answer the question: "How return instance of Object of same type as Class passed in?"

Comment: (And in this case you would use "new Testing()" anyway)

Comment: @Puce - Of course - These are instructional examples - not bullet-proof - not idealocigally correct - Down vote as necessary.

Comment: Read my answer below: you don't have to implement such a method yourself. It is useless code.

Comment: It is strictly speaking correct, of course, but IMHO not the recommended solution, since it adds more code than necessary.

Comment: @Puce - Correct - He is trying to understand Java generics.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't trying to do anything fancy with the object during the creation, what's wrong with just using a good old fashioned constructors?

You should be able to use something similar to:

```
public T getObject<T>(T obj)
{
  return obj.newInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement this method, it's already there:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29

Usage:

```
Class<T> type = ...;
T instance = type.newInstance();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Object getObject(Class clazz) {
  return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Will create a new object of the specified class. You don't have to use generics for this.

Comment: You have to use Generics, if you don't want to cast later.

Comment: yeah, you edited your question later on - Class is generic, so you can use what Chuck posted.