# Object Pool Pattern in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

So I've implemented my own Object Pool Pattern and it works just fine and as expected. Returning my "Teacher" objects from a list and creating them when there aren't any.

My question: The object being returned "Teacher" then needs to be casted into one of its sub classes which is specialised e.g. "Biology-Teacher".

What is the best way to get this kind of functionality?

Edit:
Sorry, I didn't think code was needed but here goes.

Below is the casting I was talking about. This throws a run-time exception which is my main problem.

```
  final Bio-Teacher = (Bio-Teacher) ObjectPool.getTeacher();
```

This is the code inside of my getTeacher() method.

```
 if (objectPool.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Object returned from list");
        return ObjectPool.remove(0);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Object made and returned");
        return new Teacher();
    }
```

At the moment the only objects in the pool are "Teachers" so I only need to check if there are any in the pool. Note: I'm not keeping track of the objects in use, just the ones in my pool, its part of the requirements but I appreciate the advice.

Comment: If it's a pool of general objects then no. If all objects in the pool are of a type then you should be able to use generics.

Comment: try Class class object or instanceof,cast the object to the matching subclass.

Comment: The resource requester has to know the specific type of the object being returned.  This is a common issue with JNDI in which the calling method must cast back the generic object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider having multiple object pools depending on what you want to get back.  What if you had the package structure of (and forgive me for the naming):

```
com.foo.bar.AbstractTeacher
com.foo.bar.Teacher // A factory
com.foo.bar.BioTeacher
com.foo.bar.PhysicsTeacher
...
```

Each of these classes maintains its own object pool.  BioTeacher contains just BioTeacher, while Teacher contains all the Teacher objects

Thus, you would then have code such as:

```
Teacher t = Teacher.getTeacher();
BioTeacher b = BioTeacher.getTeacher();
```

This would simplify the casting from the more generic pool as you can specify what type of teacher you want before getting one (though yes, it does make the synchronization between the Teacher class and the BioTeacher class pools more complex).

The way this would be approached by making package level methods (they can be called by other classes in the same package (notice how all the classes are in `com.foo.bar`), and unable to be called by objects outside of that package.

Filling the pool would be done with either

```
Teacher.createTeacher(BioTeacher.class)
```

Which would then register the teacher in the BioTeacher pool or:

```
BioTeacher.createTeacher()
```

Which would then register the teacher in the Teacher pool.

The tricky part if working in a multithreaded environment (something to keep in mind as this is a learning experience is in the methods `Teacher.getTeacher()` and `BioTeacher.getTeacher()` where one would possibly have a race condition where one thread gets the Teacher from getTeacher while another thread gets one from the BioTeacher.

---

Another approach to this (forget about the stuff of multiple constructors from above) is to maintain a map of `Class,List<Teacher>` within the `Teacher` class itself.  When you ask for a teacher (`Teacher.getTeacher(Teacher.class)` or `Teacher.getTeacher(BioTeacher.class)`) you look it up in the map and return an item from the appropriate list.  Furthermore, in this method (that can be synchronized) you can then find the teacher in the other list (it will always be in at least two lists (Teacher.class and BioTeacher.class)) and remove it from that list too.

Then you can make the code so that:

```
BioTeacher Teacher.getTeacher(BioTeacher.class)
```

works without additional castings.  Again, this is a learning experience and will get you into learning more about Java's generics.  (More about this approach at [How do I return an instance of an object of the same type as the class passed in using Java 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790908/java-6-how-return-instance-of-object-of-same-type-as-class-passed-in) )

Answer (score 2):

Are you are doing this as a learning exercise?

If so, o.k., but object pools, with very few exceptions, are a bad idea and harm performance.  See *Java Concurrency in Practice* section 11.4.7 "Just say no to object pooling.". Or see [Performance Myths Revisited](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/hiheiss/archive/2005/06/exposing_java_t.html). Oops- original link fails, try this one.

(Added). As for your question, don't think you can do it.  Imagine if BiologyTeacher had extra fields not in Teacher or HistoryTeacher.  They are different sizes - how could the  memory be reused?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I agree Object Pools can be performance suicide but like you assumed to begin with; This is a learning exercise.

Answer (score 2):

If your Object Pool is actually returning instances of type Bio-Teacher, then yes

```
Teacher t = ObjectPool.getTeacher();
if (t instanceof Bio-Teacher) {
  final Bio-Teacher bioTeacher = (Bio-Teacher) t;
  // do something with the Bio-Teacher.
} else {
  // do something with Teacher t (and Teacher t is not a Bio-Teacher).
}
```

You might also try adding a Bio-Teacher constructor that takes a `Teacher` and then you could

```
Bio-Teacher t = new Bio-Teacher(ObjectPool.getTeacher());
```

Comment: Its returning Teachers, it can easily be changed to do otherwise but I was looking for another way?

Comment: @user1861156 Amended my answer a little. Don't forget to return your objects to the `ObjectPool`.