# Enforce to create more than one object of the same type

Tags: java

Is there a way to avoid the invocation of the same object multiple times?

For example, I have 3 classes: `dog`, `cat` and `snake` and every classes have 3 parameters `IDNumber`, `age` and `sexe`.

Those classes implements the interface `Zoo`.

Is there a way to avoid enforces the creation of more than one `dog`?

Comment: You want to create singleton object? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
Singleton is the object that has exactly one instance at the given time

Comment: these animals should be in a `zoo`, not implement `zoo`

Comment: but what if I have 2 dogs with different ages?

Answer (score 0):

Try googling for [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java) object.

The basic concept is this:

```java
public class Dog implements Zoo {
   private static Dog INSTANCE = null;

   public static Dog getInstance() {
       if (INSTANCE == null) {
           INSTANCE = new Dog();
       }

       return INSTANCE;
   }

   private Dog(/*your parameters*/) {
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not the right direction. One zoo has one dog, another has one hundred dogs.

Comment: Please edit your question then. I can't understand what you are asking about. Maybe you are looking for a Pool?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233780/object-pool-pattern-in-java